# Seleção de elementos por classes com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Como eu faço para selecionar um elemento HTML que possua somente as classes que eu pedir? Por exemplo:

```
$('.a.b.c') -> deve retornar apenas a div1 e não todos os elementos que também possuam as classes a, b e c além de outras
```

```
<div name="div1" class="a b c"></div>
<div name="div2" class="a b c d"></div>
```

Comment: já pensou em utilizar id na div?

Comment: Essa div é gerada por um framework, não fui eu que a criei

Comment: e pegar a div pelo nome? ex: $(".a.b.c[name='div1']")

Answer (score 2):

Vais ter de fazer essa seleção em vários passos. Podias usar `$('[class="a b c"]')` mas podes ter essas classes em ordem diferente.

Assim se fizeres como escreveste `$('.a.b.c')` vais selecionar os elementos que têm pelo menos essas três classes. Para excluir outros que tenham ainda mais classes podes fazer assim:

```
var seletor = '.a.b.c';
var selecionados = $(seletor).filter(function (el) {
    var classes = seletor.split('.').filter(Boolean);
    return this.className.split(' ').filter(function (classe) {
        return classes.indexOf(classe) == -1;
    }).length == 0;
});

selecionados.html('eu!!');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvLhdy10/